# AIR Mobile app: Using same p12 certificate from different machines

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

I am using this .p12 self-signed certificate for my android mobile application. I can use this certificate from one machine in my home and it updates my app flawlessly on Google Play store.

But when I try to use this same .p12 from another machine, Google Play does not accept my app complaining that it's not using the same key.

So, Is it possible to use the same .p12 from different machines? Do I need anything more than this .p12 file?

Note: I can not afford the Digital certificate issued by various companies at this point.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Should work from any machine. What does `openssl pkcs12 -info -in your_cert.p12` print?

Comment: Hi Alex, just added the printscreen for the output of the cmd you suggested. (I have edited the image not to display the info as it is and brushed it black.. not sure, what could be done with this info)

Comment: Does your one works on different machines? ..to upload same app on android play store? Can we export and build another copy of same key to make it 'more generic' that can be used from different places/machines? Thanks.